# Codalab setup issue using python2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I am having trouble installing codalab (https://codalab.org/) using python2.7.x. The codalab site has provided a tutorial [here](https://github.com/codalab/worksheets-examples) through which one can install their CLI to interact with their server.
The tutorial says that we need to have python 2.7 and to install codalab simply run the command "pip install codalab -U --user" whereas [here](https://pypi.org/project/codalab/#files) it says, run "pip install codalab" but none of the commands work and i get the error from both of the commands.

The error trace is as follows

```
https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/relea
se-process/#python-2-support
Collecting codalab
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:365: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Server Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures.<br />
You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings SNIMissingWarning
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:149: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail.You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, seehttps://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings InsecurePlatformWarning <br />
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/78/c9/596147d4836372f07c2
463cc8ad79eba3c6b18f3a9ab50b57fbac94ea3f2/codalab-0.3.2.tar.gz
Collecting codalabworker>=0.3.2 (from codalab)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/16/7bdc06efeab5d712a55
7a0fed8d1e050dbf4769d96afac295f620e2b44a2/codalabworker-0.3.2.tar.gz <br />
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python27\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\hafiza~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-rbchpi\\codalabworker\\setup.py'"'"';__file__='"'"'c:\\users\\hafiza~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-installrbchpi\\codalabworker\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'
open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info <br />
         cwd: c:\users\hafiza~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-rbchpi\codalabworker\ <br />
    Complete output (1 lines):<br />
    **error in codalabworker setup command: "values of 'package_data' dict" must be a list of strings (got 'requirements.txt')** <br />
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.<br />
```

I have tried different versions of python from 2.7.0 to2.7.8 and the 2.7.16 but I get the same error. I have also tried the 3.7.0.

OS: windows 8.1
Python --version tried : mentioned above 
pip version tried: latest 19 for both 2.7 and 3.0 
every python tool was upgraded. 
Other links tried: could not found none related to this problem

Answer (score 0):

You may need to fix the `codalabworker/setup.py` file.

Check this: https://github.com/codalab/codalab-worksheets/commit/6e92da072e17ad7a25c287325d0795233fd2d168

Or change `package_data={'': 'requirements.txt'}` to
`package_data={'': ['requirements.txt'\]`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your concern on this one, But i am kind of newbie in some things. First thing is how am i gonna fix the issue that you have suggested in codalabworker/setup.py. Please explain a little.

Secondly how will i change 
package_data={'': 'requirements.txt'} to package_data={'': ['requirements.txt'\]

Comment: Moreover i was thinking if i download the whole github codalab project and maybe install manually somehow, like running some main function in some setup.py . is this possible ?